# Bigquery : Create table if not exist and load data using Python and Apache AirFlow

Tags: python, mysql, json, google-bigquery, airflow

First, I get all data using MySQL query from production database then store that data as `NEW LINE DELIMITED JSON` in google cloud storage, what I want to do is:

1. check if the table exists

2. if the table doesn't exist, create the table using autodetect schema

3. store data

All of this will be scheduled in airflow. What really confused me is number `2`, how can I do this in Python ? or can Airflow do this automatically?

Answer (score 7):

Airflow can do this automatically. The `create_disposition` parameter creates the table if needed. And the `autodetect` parameter does exactly what you need. This is for **Airflow 1.10.2**.

```
GCS_to_BQ = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bq',
    bucket='test_bucket',
    source_objects=['folder1/*.csv', 'folder2/*.csv'],
    destination_project_dataset_table='dest_table',
    source_format='CSV',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    bigquery_conn_id='bq-conn',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp-conn',
    autodetect=True, # This uses autodetect
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: I have same doubt, But this is for BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator. When we are creating a table using operator. We need to specify table_id='Emp_7 in parameter which is the table name.My question is If Table already exist so it should not create a table, If table not exist then only it should be created. How we can do this ??

Answer (score 3):

From BigQuery commandline, if your json file is on GCS, then [Loading JSON data with schema auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_with_schema_auto-detection) does 2 + 3 for you in one command.

Looking at AirFlow document, [GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#id123) seems doing the same thing. I checked its [source](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq.html#GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator), it simply call BigQuery **load api**. I believe it will do what you want.

When it is unclear what each argument means, you can search [BigQuery Jobs api](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load) using argument name.

E.g., to achieve 1 in your task list, you only need to specify:

**write_disposition (string) – The write disposition if the table already exists.**

But in order to know what string you need to pass as write_disposition, you have to search on BigQuery document.
[image]

Comment: I have same doubt, But this is for BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator. When we are creating a table using operator. We need to specify table_id='Emp_7 in parameter which is the table name.My question is If Table already exist so it should not create a table, If table not exist then only it should be created. How we can do this ??

Comment: It is called CreateDisposition : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/CreateDisposition